# Failed to resolve: uz.shift:colorpicker:0.5

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors, color-picker

After I updated the Android studio to 4.0 version, the color picker dependency is not working: "`implementation 'uz.shift:colorpicker:0.5@aar'`". I also try another dependencies but same issue.

**build.gradle**

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/dasar/maven" }
    maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url  "http://dl.bintray.com/dasar/maven" }

    mavenCentral()
    }

 dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //rate alert
    implementation 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"


    implementation 'uz.shift:colorpicker:0.5@aar'


    implementation 'com.github.jetradarmobile:desertplaceholder:1.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.7'
    implementation 'com.github.HoraApps:Liz:-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'

    // TODO check them out
    implementation 'com.turingtechnologies.materialscrollbar:lib:10.0.3'
    implementation 'de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.8.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
   }
```

**Error**

```
Failed to resolve: uz.shift:colorpicker:0.5
   Show in Project Structure dialog
   Affected Modules: app
```

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade the version of gradle as of now, No proper solution is available.
It will work fine in ( Gradle Version - 5.6.4)

I've tried everything still it won't go away. As the problem struck when I downloaded the latest version. I simply switched back to the previous version of gradle and It's working fine now.